# Opening Pdf on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery, pdfobject

Opening a local pdf works but if I specify a url , to access the data that is dynamically created at the server , it fails.

url : "test.pdf" // **Works**

url: "api/items/301/convert/pdf" // **FAILS** (AJAX call, see attached image[image])

I am using pdf_object.js [a javascript interface to open pdf files in the browser](http://pdfobject.com/)

Comment: Did you check gmail's file opener? Try this one: Send a PDF to yourself with gmail, go to inbox, open the mail and open the attachment in the browser. Watch the console. Can you find anything useful this way?